# Change the mouse cursor when shift key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, shift

I have a subclass `PointPanel` of `JPanel`, where I want to implement the following behavior: If the mouse hovers the instance and the shift key is pressed, the mouse cursor changes to the hand cursor; if the shift key is released, the mouse cursor changes back to the default cursor.

In order to achieve this, I tried to add a `KeyListener` in the constructor:

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            System.out.println("Shift pressed");
            PointPanel.this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            System.out.println("Shift released");
            PointPanel.this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
    }
});
```

This approach does not work.

The window which contains this panel should have the focus since it is the only visible window of the application.

What do I miss?

Comment: KeyEvents are only passed to the component with focus. I doubt the JPanel has focus. Instead you can use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for events even when a component doesn't have focus.

Comment: Is it possible to use key bindings for key presses and key releases? Using key bindings, I managed to change the cursor when the shift key is stroked, but that is not what I want to achieve. I want to change the cursor when the shift key is pressed, and change it back when the shift key is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it confusing when creating the KeyStroke.

For the pressed I had to use:

```
KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift pressed SHIFT");
```

But for the released I could use either:

```
KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SHIFT");
KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, 0, true);
```

And I used:

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an alternative for pressed: `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)`